# How can I check the size of a file in a Windows batch script every 30 minutes and send an email if any anomalies?

Tags: windows, powershell, scripting

- I've a json file in my PC. My aim is to write a script and **let it run every 30 minutes automatically**.
- **The script will take in the file name and check its size and if it's less than say 500Kb, it will trigger emails to say abc@gmail.com**

I tried writing a script but upon running this I get "else was unexpected". Here's the script :

```
@echo off
set "file="C:\CodeBases\DumpStack.log"
set MAXBYTESIZE=500000

for /f "usebackq" %%A in ("%file%") do set /a size=%%~zA

if %size% GTR %MAXBYTESIZE% (
    echo(%file% is too large
) else (
    echo(%file% is ^<^> %size% bytes long
)

pause
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, Anonymous. This is a good place to get help with a script. In order to do so, we need to see the script (an MRE Minimal, Reproducible Example), know what it is doing, and know what it should do. Please copy and paste the script into the question as text. No pictures of code. More information about how SO works is at https://stackoverflow.com/help. Please note that SO is not a free, bespoke script writing service.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @echo off
set "file="C:\CodeBases\DumpStack.log"
set MAXBYTESIZE=500000

for /f "usebackq" %%A in ("%file%") do set /a size=%%~zA

if %size% GTR %MAXBYTESIZE% (
    echo(%file% is too large
) else (
    echo(%file% is ^<^> %size% bytes long
)

pause

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I chose this question to see if I could solve it.

My test environment is a 64 bit Windows 10. I'm assuming that's okay. From the tags and the link I assume that it should be a batch script. A cron job seems to make more sense to me somehow.
In addition, the matter of sending emails seems a bit difficult to me due to password technical reasons.
Or create a spam template. Or even more set up an SMTP server.

So here is the batch script:

```
@ECHO OFF

REM -> Start batch in a new window
IF "%~1" == "" START "FileSize Checker in 30min - Mail" %comspec% /K ""%~F0" INLINE" & GOTO :Exit

REM -> Jump to label according passed parameter/arg
IF /I "%~1" == "Keychecker" GOTO :Keychecker

REM -> Settings
SET MAILSERVER=a.mail.server
SET MAILSERVERPORT=587
SET MAILUSERNAME=user
SET MAILADRESS=me@domain.xyz
SET MAILSUBJECT=File Checker in 30min - Report
SET MAILBODY=See attached logfile ( good luck ^^^^^^^^ )
SET LOGFILE=%temp%\FileSizeCheckerin30minMail.log
REM -> For testing I use the logfile (your file to check)
SET MYFILETOCHECK=%LOGFILE%
REM -> File size target bytes for switch (for kb * 1024)
SET /A TargetSize=512000
REM -> Set a higher number than 0 (max. 30) to end the loop earlier
SET /A TargetMinutes=0

REM -> Save old codepage
FOR /F "tokens=2 delims=:." %%x IN ('CHCP') DO SET cp=%%x
REM -> SET codepage according to my text language (maybe has to be changed)
CHCP 1252>NUL

REM -> Get/set current path (wo last backslash)
SET CALLPath=%~dp0
SET CALLPath=%CALLPath:~0,-1%
SET CurrentFolder=%CD%

REM -> Change directory to user temp folder (just in case)
CD /D "%temp%"

REM -> Save some vars which should be reseted at end of batch
SET CurrentTitle=cmd
REM -> Fetch Title and PID, a little bit hacky...
FOR /F "tokens=2" %%i IN ('wmic process get parentprocessid^,name^|find "cmd"') DO SET CmdPID=%%i
FOR /F "tokens=2" %%i IN ('tasklist /fi "pid eq %CmdPID%" /fo list /v') DO SET CurrentTitle=%%i

REM -> Workarround for flickering / remove cursor
FOR /F %%e IN ('ECHO Prompt $E^|cmd') DO SET "\E=%%e"

REM -> Activate extensions
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion

REM -> Downsize the console
REM FOR /f "skip=3 delims=: tokens=2" %%A IN ('MODE CON') DO (
REM    IF DEFINED CONLINES IF NOT DEFINED CONCOLS SET /a CONCOLS=%%A
REM    IF NOT DEFINED CONLINES SET /a CONLINES=%%A
REM )
FOR /F "tokens=3" %%A IN ('reg query HKCU\Console /v WindowSize') DO SET /A CONLINES=%%A/65535
FOR /F "tokens=3" %%A IN ('reg query HKCU\Console /v WindowSize') DO SET /A "CONCOLS=%%A&0xffff
MODE CON cols=85 lines=22

REM -> Ensure previous temp files removed in case program exited incorrectly
DEL /Q /F "%LOGFILE%" 2>NUL
DEL /Q /F "%temp%\CMDrun.log" 2>NUL
DEL /Q /F "%temp%\CMDend.log" 2>NUL
DEL /Q /F "%temp%\CMDchoice.log" 2>NUL

REM -> Internal threads (almost empty this time - only the color setter and the good old xcopy abuse)
CALL :setESC
START /B /SHARED "Keychecker" "%~F0" Keychecker 2>NUL

REM -> This will remove the cursor
<NUL SET /P "=%\E%[?25l"


REM -> Prepair for a new loop
:PREPAIR

>"%LOGFILE%" ECHO TIMER START

REM -> Setup a timeing system
SET /A TIMER_XMIL=%time:~-1%
SET /A TIMER_YMIL=%time:~-2,-1%
SET /A TIMER_XSEC=%time:~-4,-3%
SET /A TIMER_YSEC=%time:~-5,-4%
SET /A TIMER_XMIN=%time:~-7,-6%
SET /A TIMER_YMIN=%time:~-8,-7%
IF "%TIMER_YMIL%" == "0" (
   SET /A TIMER_MIL=%TIMER_XMIL%
) ELSE (
   SET /A TIMER_MIL=%TIMER_YMIL%%TIMER_XMIL%
)
IF "%TIMER_YSEC%" == "0" (
   SET /A TIMER_SEC=%TIMER_XSEC%
) ELSE (
   SET /A TIMER_SEC=%TIMER_YSEC%%TIMER_XSEC%
)
IF "%TIMER_YMIN%" == "0" (
   SET /A TIMER_MIN=%TIMER_XMIN%
) ELSE (
   SET /A TIMER_MIN=%TIMER_YMIN%%TIMER_XMIN%
)
IF %TIMER_SEC% EQU 59 (
   SET /A TIMER_SEC_T=0
) ELSE (
   SET /A TIMER_SEC_T=%TIMER_SEC% + 1
)
IF %TIMER_MIN% LSS 30 (
   SET /A TEATIME=%TIMER_MIN% + 30
) ELSE (
   SET /A TEATIME=%TIMER_MIN% - 30
)
SET /A CURRENTZZZ=7
SET NOSENDMAIL=NOPE


REM -> The big main loop...
:LOOP
SET /A TIMER_XMIL=%time:~-1%
SET /A TIMER_YMIL=%time:~-2,-1%
SET /A TIMER_XSEC=%time:~-4,-3%
SET /A TIMER_YSEC=%time:~-5,-4%
SET /A TIMER_XMIN=%time:~-7,-6%
SET /A TIMER_YMIN=%time:~-8,-7%
IF "%TIMER_YMIL%" == "0" (
   SET /A TIMER_MIL=%TIMER_XMIL%
) ELSE (
   SET /A TIMER_MIL=%TIMER_YMIL%%TIMER_XMIL%
)
IF "%TIMER_YSEC%" == "0" (
   SET /A TIMER_SEC=%TIMER_XSEC%
) ELSE (
   SET /A TIMER_SEC=%TIMER_YSEC%%TIMER_XSEC%
)
IF "%TIMER_YMIN%" == "0" (
   SET /A TIMER_MIN=%TIMER_XMIN%
) ELSE (
   SET /A TIMER_MIN=%TIMER_YMIN%%TIMER_XMIN%
)

REM -> Synchronize msec to sec (target 1 sec per run)
IF NOT %TIMER_SEC% EQU %TIMER_SEC_T% GOTO :LOOP

REM -> Exit the loop if temp file exists (Keychecker passed)
(IF EXIST "%temp%\CMDend.log" GOTO :EndOfBatch) 2>NUL
REM -> Handle choices
IF EXIST "%temp%\CMDchoice.log" IF NOT DEFINED GETKEY FOR /F "usebackq tokens=1 delims=" %%X IN ("%temp%\CMDchoice.log") DO SET GETKEY=%%X
REM -> r)   Restart
IF "!GETKEY!" == "r" (
   SET GETKEY=DONE
   DEL /Q /F "%temp%\CMDchoice.log" 2>NUL
   SET "GETKEY="
   GOTO :PREPAIR
)
REM -> s)   Set mail password
IF "!GETKEY!" == "s" (
   SET GETKEY=DONE
   DEL /Q /F "%temp%\CMDchoice.log" 2>NUL
   SET "GETKEY="
   SET FROMLABEL=LOOP
   GOTO :SETPW
)

REM -> Determinate remaining time
IF %TIMER_SEC% EQU 59 (
   SET /A TIMER_SEC_T=0
) ELSE (
   SET /A TIMER_SEC_T=%TIMER_SEC% + 1
)
SET /A TIMELEFT=%TEATIME% - %TIMER_MIN%
IF %TIMELEFT% LSS 0 SET /A TIMELEFT=60 + %TIMELEFT%
SET /A SECDUMMY=59 - %TIMER_SEC%

REM -> Log the time
>>"%LOGFILE%" ECHO %date% - %time%

REM -> If time is over ...
IF %TIMELEFT% EQU %TargetMinutes% IF %SECDUMMY% EQU 0 GOTO :SLEEPOVER

REM -> Output text animation
FOR /L %%G IN (0,1,29) DO (
   SET PERCENT[%%G]=_
   IF %TIMELEFT% LEQ %%G SET PERCENT[%%G]=X
)
SET /A CURRENTZZZ=%CURRENTZZZ% + 1
IF %CURRENTZZZ% GTR 7 (
   SET /A CURRENTZZZ=-1
   SET ZZZ[0]=%ESC%[30m
   SET ZZZ[1]=%ESC%[30m
   SET ZZZ[2]=%ESC%[30m
   SET ZZZ[3]=%ESC%[30m
   SET ZZZ[4]=%ESC%[30m
   SET ZZZ[5]=%ESC%[30m
   SET ZZZ[6]=%ESC%[30m
   SET ZZZ[7]=%ESC%[30m
) ELSE (
   SET ZZZ[%CURRENTZZZ%]=%ESC%[33m
)
<NUL SET /P "=%\E%[?25l"
CLS
ECHO.
ECHO.
ECHO.     %ESC%[44m%ESC%[33m%ESC%[1m    Sleeping well inside the loop. %TIMELEFT% Minutes and %SECDUMMY% Seconds left.    %ESC%[0m
ECHO.
ECHO.         %ESC%[31mOPTIONS: %ESC%[35mr%ESC%[31m -^> Restart    %ESC%[35mq%ESC%[31m -^> Quit%ESC%[0m    %ESC%[35ms%ESC%[31m -^> Set Mail Password%ESC%[0m
ECHO.
ECHO.                         [!PERCENT[29]!][!PERCENT[28]!][!PERCENT[27]!][!PERCENT[26]!][!PERCENT[25]!][!PERCENT[24]!][!PERCENT[23]!][!PERCENT[22]!][!PERCENT[21]!][!PERCENT[20]!]
ECHO.                         [!PERCENT[19]!][!PERCENT[18]!][!PERCENT[17]!][!PERCENT[16]!][!PERCENT[15]!][!PERCENT[14]!][!PERCENT[13]!][!PERCENT[12]!][!PERCENT[11]!][!PERCENT[10]!]
ECHO.                         [!PERCENT[9]!][!PERCENT[8]!][!PERCENT[7]!][!PERCENT[6]!][!PERCENT[5]!][!PERCENT[4]!][!PERCENT[3]!][!PERCENT[2]!][!PERCENT[1]!][!PERCENT[0]!]
ECHO.
ECHO.
ECHO.
ECHO.
ECHO.                                         !ZZZ[7]!Z
ECHO.                                      !ZZZ[6]!z
ECHO.                                   !ZZZ[5]!Z
ECHO.                                !ZZZ[4]!z
ECHO.                             !ZZZ[3]!Z
ECHO.                          !ZZZ[2]!z
ECHO.                       !ZZZ[1]!Z
ECHO.                    !ZZZ[0]!z
TITLE FileSize Checker in 30min - Mail         %date%   -   %time%

GOTO :LOOP


REM -> Simple password storage, better than directly in the script, but probably not secure enough.
:SETPW
CLS
ECHO.
ECHO.
ECHO.     %ESC%[44m%ESC%[33m%ESC%[1m    This will set the password for your E-Mail account.    %ESC%[0m
ECHO.
ECHO.
ECHO.
<NUL SET /P "=%\E%[?25h"
<NUL SET /P=%ESC%[31m         Please enter password: 
SET /P MAILPW=
TITLE FileSize Checker in 30min - Mail - Set Password
>"%temp%\CMDrun.log" ECHO Continue
IF "%FROMLABEL%" == "LOOP" (
   SET /A TIMER_XSEC=!time:~-4,-3!
   SET /A TIMER_YSEC=!time:~-5,-4!
   IF "!TIMER_YSEC!" == "0" (
      SET /A TIMER_SEC=!TIMER_XSEC!
   ) ELSE (
      SET /A TIMER_SEC=!TIMER_YSEC!!TIMER_XSEC!
   )
   IF !TIMER_SEC! EQU 59 (
      SET /A TIMER_SEC_T=0
   ) ELSE (
      SET /A TIMER_SEC_T=!TIMER_SEC! + 1
   )
   SET /A TIMELEFTTEST=%TEATIME% - %TIMER_MIN% - 1
   IF !TIMELEFTTEST! LSS 0 SET /A TIMELEFTTEST=61 + !TIMELEFTTEST!
   IF !TIMELEFTTEST! GTR 29 GOTO :PREPAIR
   IF !TIMELEFTTEST! LSS 1 GOTO :PREPAIR
)
GOTO :%FROMLABEL%


REM -> Check for keypress q = quit / r = restart / s = password
:Keychecker
>"%temp%\CMDrun.log" ECHO Running
:KeycheckerLoop
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
FOR /F "Delims=" %%A IN ('xcopy /w "%temp%\CMDrun.log" "%temp%\CMDrun.log" 2^>NUL') DO (
   IF NOT DEFINED Key SET "Key=%%A"
)
IF DEFINED Key (
   SET "Key=!Key:~-1!"
   IF "!Key!" == "r" (
      >"%temp%\CMDchoice.log" ECHO !Key!
   ) ELSE IF "!Key!" == "q" (
      >"%temp%\CMDend.log" ECHO !Key!
   ) ELSE IF "!Key!" == "s" (
      >"%temp%\CMDchoice.log" ECHO !Key!
      >"%temp%\CMDrun.log" ECHO Waiting
      SET DOWAIT=YE
   )
   (IF EXIST "%temp%\CMDend.log" GOTO :Exit) 2>NUL
)
:KeycheckerWaitLoop
IF "!DOWAIT!S" == "YES" (
   SET /P ISWAITING=<"%temp%\CMDrun.log"
   IF "!ISWAITING!" == "Waiting" (
      ping 1.2.3.4 -n 1 -w 1000 >NUL
      GOTO :KeycheckerWaitLoop
   )
)
ENDLOCAL
GOTO :KeycheckerLoop


REM -> Colors
:setESC
FOR /F "tokens=1,2 delims=#" %%a IN ('"PROMPT #$H#$E# & echo on & for %%b in (1) do rem"') DO (
   SET ESC=%%b
   GOTO :Exit
)


REM -> I actually mean well-rested, whatever ;)
:SLEEPOVER
SET ResultGood=YES
FOR /F "usebackq" %%A IN ('%MYFILETOCHECK%') DO SET Size=%%~zA
REM -> Not sure if that is right according to size of the file
IF %Size% LEQ %TargetSize% (
   SET Result=File is less or equal 500k : %Size%b
   SET ResultColor=%ESC%[42m
) ELSE (
   SET ResultGood=NOPE
   SET Result=Houston^, we have a problem. File is %Size%b :-(
   SET ResultColor=%ESC%[41m
)
>>"%LOGFILE%" ECHO "%Result%"

SET MAILMESSAGESEND=Sending mail now ...
SET MAILMESSAGENOTSEND=No password defined, skipping send mail
SET MAILMESSAGENOTSENDPW=Password defined but send mail skipped
SET MSGSWITCH=FALSE
SET CLSWITCH=TRUE
IF NOT DEFINED MAILPW SET MSGSWITCH=TRUE
GOTO :SLEEPOVERTEXT

:SLEEPOVERTEXTCLSWITCH
SET CLSWITCH=FALSE
:SLEEPOVERTEXT
CLS
ECHO.
ECHO.
ECHO.     %ESC%[44m%ESC%[33m%ESC%[1m    Dreaming over. Time to wake up. Let's see..    %ESC%[0m
ECHO.
ECHO.     %ResultColor%    %Result%    %ESC%[0m
ECHO.
ECHO.
ECHO.         %ESC%[31mOPTIONS: %ESC%[35mr%ESC%[31m -^> Restart    %ESC%[35mq%ESC%[31m -^> Quit%ESC%[0m    %ESC%[35ms%ESC%[31m -^> Set Mail Password%ESC%[0m
ECHO.
ECHO.
IF NOT DEFINED MAILPW ECHO.   !MAILMESSAGENOTSEND!
IF DEFINED MAILPW IF "%MSGSWITCH%" == "FALSE" ECHO.   !MAILMESSAGESEND!
IF DEFINED MAILPW IF "%MSGSWITCH%" == "TRUE" ECHO.   !MAILMESSAGENOTSENDPW!
REM -> This is the base64 encoded script to send the mail. Encoded because I think it's a smart way to include a script
IF DEFINED MAILPW IF NOT "!NOSENDMAIL!" == "YES" (
   powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -command "'%MAILSERVER%', '%MAILSERVERPORT%', '%MAILUSERNAME%', '!MAILPW!', '%MAILADRESS%', '%MAILSUBJECT%', '%MAILBODY%', '%LOGFILE%', ''" | powershell.exe -encodedcommand "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"
)
ECHO.
ECHO.
ECHO.         Auto-Restart in T- ping 100 * 200
ECHO.

TITLE FileSize Checker in 30min - Mail - Result
SET NOSENDMAIL=YES

IF DEFINED MAILPW IF "!CLSWITCH!" == "TRUE" (
   SET MAILMESSAGESEND=Email sent
   GOTO :SLEEPOVERTEXTCLSWITCH
)

ping 1.2.3.4 -n 1 -w 100 >NUL
SET /A COUNTDOWN=199

:TPING
<NUL SET /P "=%\E%[?25l"
REM -> Exit the loop if temp file exists (Keychecker passed)
(IF EXIST "%temp%\CMDend.log" GOTO :EndOfBatch) 2>NUL
REM -> Handle choices (again)
IF EXIST "%temp%\CMDchoice.log" IF NOT DEFINED GETKEY FOR /F "usebackq tokens=1 delims=" %%X IN ("%temp%\CMDchoice.log") DO SET GETKEY=%%X
REM -> r)   Restart
IF "!GETKEY!" == "r" (
   SET GETKEY=DONE
   DEL /Q /F "%temp%\CMDchoice.log" 2>NUL
   SET "GETKEY="
   GOTO :PREPAIR
)
REM -> s)   Set mail password
IF "!GETKEY!" == "s" (
   SET GETKEY=DONE
   DEL /Q /F "%temp%\CMDchoice.log" 2>NUL
   SET "GETKEY="
   SET MAILMESSAGESEND=Email sent
   SET MAILMESSAGENOTSEND=No password defined, send mail skipped
   SET FROMLABEL=SLEEPOVERTEXT
   GOTO :SETPW
)

TITLE FileSize Checker in 30min - Mail - Result - Countdown %COUNTDOWN%
SET /A COUNTDOWN=%COUNTDOWN% - 1
ping 1.2.3.4 -n 1 -w 100 >NUL
IF %COUNTDOWN% NEQ 0 GOTO :TPING
GOTO :PREPAIR


REM -> Reset cursor, directory and other things (note to myself: don't forget ENDLOCAL)
:EndOfBatch
ping 1.2.3.4 -n 1 -w 200 >NUL
DEL /Q /F "%temp%\CMDrun.log" 2>NUL
DEL /Q /F "%temp%\CMDend.log" 2>NUL
DEL /Q /F "%temp%\CMDchoice.log" 2>NUL
<NUL SET /P "=%\E%[?25h"
MODE CON cols=!CONCOLS! lines=!CONLINES!
ENDLOCAL
CHCP %cp%>NUL
TITLE %CurrentTitle%
CD /D %CurrentFolder%
ping 1.2.3.4 -n 1 -w 100 >NUL
taskkill /PID %CmdPID%


:Exit
```

I created a base64 powershell script as the mail sender. To easy include it into the batch script. The sender and receiver are the same as I want to send the log file to myself. Since it's difficult to send params to a base64 script, I use a pipe trick that I found in the net. I'm not happy with this solution because the output of the params are almost not possible to >null.

```
param
(
    [Parameter(Mandatory)]
    [string[]]
    $passedArgs
)
CLS
if ($passedArgs[$passedArgs.count] -eq "") { $passedArgs[$passedArgs.count] = $null; }
if ($passedArgs.count -lt 7) {
    Write-Host "Usage:  SendReportMail  'SERVER',  'PORT',  'USER',  'PASS',  'MAIL-ADRESS', 'SUBJECT',  'MAIL-TEXT'"
    Write-Host "Optional:  'ATTACHMENT-FILE-PATH' [default: null],  'SECURITY-PROTOCOL' [default: TLS12],  'EnableSSL' 0 / 1 [default: 1]"
    [System.Environment]::Exit(1)
}
if ($passedArgs[8] -ne $null) { [System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = $passedArgs[8]; }
else { [System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = "TLS12"; }
$message = new-object Net.Mail.MailMessage;
$message.From = $passedArgs[4];
$message.To.Add($passedArgs[4]);
$message.Subject = $passedArgs[5];
$messageIsBodyHtml = $False;
$message.Body = $passedArgs[6];
if ($passedArgs[7] -ne $null -and $passedArgs[7] -ne "null") {
    $attachment = New-Object Net.Mail.Attachment($passedArgs[7]);
    $message.Attachments.Add($attachment);
}
$smtp = new-object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($passedArgs[0], $passedArgs[1]);
if ($passedArgs[9] -ne "0") { $smtp.EnableSSL = $true; }
else { $smtp.EnableSSL = $false; }
$smtp.Credentials = New-Object Management.Automation.PSCredential $passedArgs[2], ($passedArgs[3] | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force)
$smtp.send($message);
if ($passedArgs[7] -ne $null -and $passedArgs[7] -ne "null") { $attachment.Dispose(); }
```

The batch animation has the well-known flicker effect. That was a hard nut. I finally found a solution (net wasn't helpful):
If you combine the echo's in a single line (& echo. BLA ...) it looks very smooth. I didn't do that because of readability of the code.

Since I don't think it's a good idea to save a password in a file, I added a password user input. That's certainly not ideal, but it's probably better.

Over all, it works. I received the mails. Was fun to create. But definitely not purposed for professional use.

The batch script doesn't check if the mail was successfully sent. It only print out if it attempt to call the ps script. For a success check the follow steps have to be done:

- Check the errorlevel inside the ps script and out the result to a temp file
- Parse the out file inside the batch and print out the result

And ofcorse a batch script is a little out to date... ;)

[image]